# edit pandas dataframe fields based on key in grouping

Tags: python, pandas

Given this dataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
  a = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'company_id': [11,11,22,33,55],
    'accSync': [True, False, False, False, True]
  })
```

I need to modify all rows for a given `company_id` based on the `accSync` field being True, meaning that if any row for a given `company_id` has a true in it, all rows for that `company_id` need to be updated to be true as well.

In this case, `company_id` 11 has a `True` in it and therefore row 2 should be updated to be `2, 11, True` as well while rows 1,3,4,5 should remain unaffected.

I tried using a combination if `groupby` and `any` but aren't getting anywhere.

Comment: `a.groupby('company_id')['accSync'].transform('any')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `transform`

```
a.groupby('company_id')['accSync'].transform('max')
Out[131]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: accSync, dtype: bool
```

---

Assign it back

```
a['accSync']= a.groupby('company_id')['accSync'].transform('max')
```

Comment: this just returns the changed values, it does not update the original dataframe / return a new one with the updated rows. I found a solution and will post momentarily

Comment: @Killerpixler you should assign it back`a['accSync']= a.groupby('company_id')['accSync'].transform('max')
`

Comment: Perfect, please edit your answer and I'll accept / upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
def checker(df):
    df["accSync"] = df["accSync"].any()
    return df

new_df = a.groupby(by="company_id").apply(checker)
```

Result:

```
   id  company_id  accSync
0   1          11     True
1   2          11     True
2   3          22    False
3   4          33    False
4   5          55     True
```